# Why I read data from endpoint in C# without XML tags?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

When I use Postman or a web browser I have a https response like this:

```
<RESPONSE>
 <METAINF>
   <TIMESTAMP>2021-11-25 18:56:28.437</TIMESTAMP>
   <OPERATION>company.list</OPERATION>
   <VERSION>1.0</VERSION>
   <PARAMETERS>
      <PARAMETER>
         <NAME>req_id</NAME>
         <VALUE>202111251856107621</VALUE>
      </PARAMETER>
      <PARAMETER>
         <NAME>username</NAME>
         <VALUE>zen</VALUE>
      </PARAMETER>
   </PARAMETERS>
 </METAINF>
 <STATUS>OK</STATUS>
</RESPONSE>
```

In my ASP.NET C# procedure I've in a string variable only values without XML formatting:

```
2021-11-25 18:56:28.437company.list1.0req_id202111251921553540usernamezenOK
```

This is my code:

```
        string url = "https://..../company/list";
        string username = "zen";
        string req_id = GetTimestamp(DateTime.Now);

        url += "?username=" + username
                + "&req_id=" + req_id;
                
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
        request.Accept = "application/xml";
        request.ContentType = "application/xml";
        request.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");

        request.Method = "GET";

        string responseValue = "";

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())       // Go query 
        {
            {
                using (Stream responseStream_1 = response.GetResponseStream())                  // Load the response stream
                {
                    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream_1))      // Load the stream reader to read the response
                    {
                        responseValue = streamReader.ReadToEnd();                       // Read the entire response and store it in the siteContent variable
                    }
                }
            }
            response.Close();
        }

        // responseValue have only values without xml tags !?
```

How can I get data with XML tags?

Comment: I guess you added the xml response to a webpage. The response contains the xml tags, but they are not shown in the browser, because the xml tags are interpreted like html. You need to encode the string.

Comment: Its outer servis and I can't chnge it. In Browser request work ok (I can see xml tags), but in my code I doesn't have it in string variable.

Comment: The accept header removing doesn't help

Comment: I bet your variable have the tags, you just dont display it properly

Comment: Corect! Many, many thanks!